# How to get string array method data into list or data set?

Tags: c#

I have like below method in web service how to assign that abc method into any `DataSet` or `List`

C# Code:

```
public string[] abc(string a, string b)
{
}

dataset ds=new dataset();
ds.abc("Hi","Hello");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Do you want like a List containing `Hi,Hello` ?

Comment: The question wants to put a string[] into a dataset, that is all....

Comment: You want to create an extension method?

Comment: The question wants to put a string[] into a dataset

Comment: how to call string array method into another method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Convert string array to dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583082/c-sharp-convert-string-array-to-dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correct:

```
 internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] array = new [] { "Hi", "Hello"};
            DataSet dataSet = array.AssignToDataSet();
        }    


        private static DataSet AssignToDataSet(this string[] myArray)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add();
            dataTable.Columns.Add();
            Array.ForEach(myArray, c => dataTable.Rows.Add()[0] = c);
            return dataSet;
        }
    }
```

That code creates a dataset with a table with 1 column and a row per item in the array!